# How to check if string contains particular character?

Tags: c, string

How can I check if a string contains a particular, given character?

Comment: strcmp but its compares whole string to single character so results are ...

Comment: How do you check if one character is the particular one? How about the next character?

Comment: [`strchr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/)

Comment: I upvoted this (at this time back up to -4), because it is ***YET ANOTHER*** example of 1. pile on, and 2. inappropriate and overzealous closure.  In that help center, this question is *not* disallowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite trivially, actually. Here is a sample snippet. This will locate first occurrence of a character in string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() 
{
    const char* haystack = "self";
    const char needle = 'l';
    size_t len = strlen(haystack);
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if(haystack[i] == needle) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Found char '%c' in '%s' at position %d\n", needle, haystack, (i+1));
        break;
      }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? `strchr` already exists.

Comment: Knowing how to implement this basic algorithm is important.

Comment: An example implementation of strchr can be found [here](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/strchr), which mimics the semantics of the C library's version. One major difference is that the null terminator is considered a part of the string.

Comment: @self, I quite agree.  The question shows that there may be a fundamental gap in how strings are managed in C.  Your answer, while very verbose, addresses this.